# unable to boot kernel ion A53 (devicetree?)

Tags: linux-kernel, xilinx, device-tree

I am trying to boot a Linux kernel on an A53 cpu (inside a ZU5 from xilinx).
I have two hard. The first is a custom PCB with a ZU5. The second is the ZCU102 SDK with the zu9eg.

Here the boot log :

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.19 (build_station) (aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc.br_real (B3
[    0.000000] Machine model: ZynqMP
[    0.000000] earlycon: cdns0 at MMIO 0x00000000ff000000 (options '115200n8')
[    0.000000] printk: bootconsole [cdns0] enabled
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Invalid device tree blob header
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000007fefffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000800000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone Normal: 256 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 256 MiB at 0x000000006fc00000
[    0.000000] Failed to find device node for boot cpu
[    0.000000] missing boot CPU MPIDR, not enabling secondaries
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s32600 r8192 d28840 u69632
[    0.000000] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 845719
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1033987
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlycon clk_ignore_unused
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x000000006bc00000-0x000000006fc00000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3779764K/4193280K available (8448K kernel code, 692K rwdata, 2232K rodata, 1472K)
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x3f0/0x5fc with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    0.000000] Kernel panic - not syncing: Unable to initialise architected timer.
[    0.000000] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.19 #7
[    0.000000] Hardware name: ZynqMP SL300 (DT)
[    0.000000] Call trace:
[    0.000000]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x190
[    0.000000]  show_stack+0x18/0x30
[    0.000000]  dump_stack_lvl+0x7c/0xa0
[    0.000000]  dump_stack+0x18/0x34
[    0.000000]  panic+0x14c/0x2f8
[    0.000000]  time_init+0x30/0x4c
[    0.000000]  start_kernel+0x4fc/0x5fc
[    0.000000]  __primary_switched+0xa4/0xac
[    0.000000] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Unable to initialise architected timer. ]---
```

The second hard :

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.19 (build_station) (aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2022.11-rc3-13-g43899226b2) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38) #2 SMP Fri Dec 2 12:32:23 2
[    0.000000] Machine model: ZynqMP
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000007fefffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000800000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000087fffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone Normal: 256 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 256 MiB at 0x000000006b800000
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    0.000000] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
[    0.000000] psci: MIGRATE_INFO_TYPE not supported.
[    0.000000] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.2
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 18 pages/cpu s34456 r8192 d31080 u73728
[    0.000000] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 845719
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1033987
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x000000007bf00000-0x000000007ff00000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3771452K/4193280K available (13952K kernel code, 912K rwdata, 3908K rodata, 2048K init, 336K bss, 159684K reserved, 262144K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] GIC: Adjusting CPU interface base to 0x00000000f902f000
```

On the second hard the Linux boots and I managed to use the same device tree.
I can see a difference : there is no psci detection with the first hard.

I need to know if it can be an hardware issue.

Thanks for help

Comment: Why wouldn't it be just what it says: `Invalid device tree blob header`? Can you read the flash?

Comment: Yes I saw that but the `Kernel command line:  earlycon clk_ignore_unused`  and `Machine model: ZynqMP` are from the device tree. So the device tree seems to be read.

Comment: FYI this is the wrong site, as it's not a programming question. Maybe it fits on [su] or [unix.se] (just read the guidelines first)